# Using the date from DatePicker in the url for sunrise/sunset webservice

Tags: java, android, android-datepicker

Okayyyy, so I'm stuck and could do with some help :)

In my code at the moment today's date is being read into the webservice url using the following snippet of code:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
System.out.println("Current time => " + c.getTime());
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM");
String formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());
```

I want today's date to be displayed but I also want the user to be able to select a different date from the DatePicker and find the sunrise/sunset values for that particular date.

I'm guessing this is simple and I'm just being a bit dim so any help would be appreciated, here is my code:

```
package richgrundy.learnphotography;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.protocol.BasicHttpContext;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SunriseSunset extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    public Button getLocation;
    public Button setLocationJapan;
    public TextView LongCoord;
    public TextView LatCoord;
    public double longitude;
    public double latitude;
    public LocationManager lm;
    public Spinner Locationspinner;
    public DateDialogFragment frag;
    public Button date;
    public Calendar now;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sunrisesunset);

        //Setting onClickListener for Calculate Sunrise/Sunset Button
        findViewById(R.id.CalculateSunriseSunset).setOnClickListener(this);

        //Sets up LocationManager to enable GPS data to be accessed.
        lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 1,
                new MyLocationListener());

        //Declares Latitude and Longitude TextViews
        LatCoord = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.LatCoord);
        LongCoord = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.LongCoord);

        //Declares for Location Spinner/Dropdown
        addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection();

        //Date
        now = Calendar.getInstance();
        date = (Button)findViewById(R.id.date_button);
        date.setText(String.valueOf(now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)+1)+"-"+String.valueOf(now.get(Calendar.MONTH))+"-"+String.valueOf(now.get(Calendar.YEAR)));
        date.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showDialog();
            }
        });

    }
    // More date
    public void showDialog() {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction(); //get the fragment
        frag = DateDialogFragment.newInstance(this, new DateDialogFragmentListener(){
            public void updateChangedDate(int year, int month, int day){
                date.setText(String.valueOf(day)+"-"+String.valueOf(month+1)+"-"+String.valueOf(year));
                now.set(year, month, day);
            }
        }, now);

        frag.show(ft, "DateDialogFragment");

    }

    public interface DateDialogFragmentListener{
        //this interface is a listener between the Date Dialog fragment and the activity to update the buttons date
        public void updateChangedDate(int year, int month, int day);
    }

    public void addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection() {
        Locationspinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Locationspinner);
        Locationspinner
                .setOnItemSelectedListener(new CustomOnItemSelectedListener(
                        this));
    }

    public void setLocationFrance() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        LatCoord.setText("65.4112");
        LongCoord.setText("85.8337");
    }

    public void setLocationIndia() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        LatCoord.setText("21.4112");
        LongCoord.setText("105.8337");
    }

    public void setLocationJapan() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        LatCoord.setText("21.4112");
        LongCoord.setText("15.8337");
    }

    protected void showCurrentLocation() {
        // This is called to find current location based on GPS data and sends
        // this to LongCoord and LatCoord TextViews
        Location location = lm
                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
        longitude = location.getLongitude();

        LongCoord.setText(Double.toString(longitude));
        LatCoord.setText(Double.toString(latitude));
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.CalculateSunriseSunset);
        b.setClickable(false);
        new LongRunningGetIO().execute();
    }

    private class LongRunningGetIO extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        protected String getASCIIContentFromEntity(HttpEntity entity)
                throws IllegalStateException, IOException {
            InputStream in = entity.getContent();
            StringBuffer out = new StringBuffer();
            int n = 1;
            while (n > 0) {
                byte[] b = new byte[4096];
                n = in.read(b);
                if (n > 0)
                    out.append(new String(b, 0, n));
            }
            return out.toString();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();

            // Finds todays date and adds that into the URL
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            System.out.println("Current time => " + c.getTime());
            SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM");
            String formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());

            String finalURL = "http://www.earthtools.org/sun/"
                    + LatCoord.getText().toString().trim() + "/"
                    + LongCoord.getText().toString().trim() + "/"
                    + formattedDate + "/99/0";
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(finalURL);
            String text = null;

            try {
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet,
                        localContext);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                text = getASCIIContentFromEntity(entity);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return e.getLocalizedMessage();
            }
            return text;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String results) {
            if (results != null) {
                try {

                    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                            .newInstance();
                    DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
                    InputSource s = new InputSource(new StringReader(results));
                    Document doc = dBuilder.parse(s);
                    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
                    TextView tvSunrise = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Sunrise);
                    TextView tvSunset = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Sunset);
                    tvSunrise.setText(doc.getElementsByTagName("sunrise").item(0).getTextContent());
                    tvSunset.setText(doc.getElementsByTagName("sunset").item(0).getTextContent());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.CalculateSunriseSunset);
            b.setClickable(true);
        }
    }

    class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    }
}
```

DateFragmentDialog:

```
package richgrundy.learnphotography;


import java.util.Calendar;

import richgrundy.learnphotography.SunriseSunset.DateDialogFragmentListener;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.DatePicker;

public class DateDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    public static String TAG = "DateDialogFragment";
    static Context mContext; //I guess hold the context that called it. Needed when making a DatePickerDialog. I guess its needed when conncting the fragment with the context
    static int mYear;
    static int mMonth;
    static int mDay;
    static DateDialogFragmentListener mListener;

    public static DateDialogFragment newInstance(Context context, DateDialogFragmentListener listener, Calendar now) {
        DateDialogFragment dialog = new DateDialogFragment();
        mContext = context;
        mListener = listener;
        mYear = now.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        mMonth = now.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        mDay = now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);  
        return dialog;
    }


    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return new DatePickerDialog(mContext, mDateSetListener, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
    }


    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                int dayOfMonth) {
            mYear = year;
            mMonth = monthOfYear;
            mDay = dayOfMonth;

            mListener.updateChangedDate(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
        }
    };
}
```

And just in case you want it here is the layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/fabricc"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".SunriseSunset" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Date:"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <Button 
        android:id="@+id/date_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="03-18-2012"
        android:onClick="clickMe"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout04"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Location:"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/Locationspinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:entries="@array/location_array"
            android:padding="10dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout343"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="4" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView23"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Coordinates:"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/LatCoord"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="10dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/LongCoord"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="10dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/CalculateSunriseSunset"
        style="@style/sub_menu"
        android:background="@drawable/blue_menu_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="Calculate Sunrise/Sunset Time" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayoutasdsd"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView122"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Sunrise:"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Sunrise"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="00:00:00"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayoutasdsad"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView133"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Sunset:"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Sunset"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="00:00:00"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Like I said any help would be massively appreciated =)

Thanks for looking.

Comment: What are you stuck on? Be specific, please.

Comment: All of it...I don't know how to get the variable from the DatePicker into the url of the webservice.

Comment: @Athoul wow, your project is getting big.

Comment: @EntryLevelDev Works perfectly thanks, one last thing though. Is there a way to display the date in the button in this kind of format `28th March 2013` rather than the `28-03-2013` that is displayed at the moment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure about your requirement but I guess you can try changing from

```
String formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());
```

to

```
String formattedDate = df.format(now.getTime());
```

This is pretty dirty but I think it should work just fine.
Your doInBackground should look like this:

```
@Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();

        // Finds todays date and adds that into the URL
        //Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        //System.out.println("Current time => " + c.getTime());
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM");
        String formattedDate = df.format(now.getTime());

        String finalURL = "http://www.earthtools.org/sun/"
                + LatCoord.getText().toString().trim() + "/"
                + LongCoord.getText().toString().trim() + "/"
                + formattedDate + "/99/0";
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(finalURL);
        String text = null;

        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet,
                    localContext);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            text = getASCIIContentFromEntity(entity);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return e.getLocalizedMessage();
        }
        return text;
    }
```

Hope this helps.